# ffmpeg resize video but maintain audio quality

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=640x360,setdar=16:9 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -profile:v main -crf 18 -b:a 189k output.mp4
```

My input video file: res: 720p and audio bitrate: 189kbps. I heard choosing audio bitrate same as source makes audio quality of output file is worse.

My question is how to maintain the audio quality of video file?

My sub question is the preset veryslow affects anything to the audio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use `-c:a copy`

You can [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-mux) the audio instead of re-encoding it. Think of it like a copy and paste. Your command would then look like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=640x360,setdar=16:9 -c:v libx264 -preset veryslow -profile:v main -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

Since the audio is just being copied there will be no quality loss.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use IVCompressor mentioned in below link.

It can resize video with good quality as well as retaining the same audio quality.

You can customize the attributes also. It is built on top of FFMPEG. So the quality will be good

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63335797/how-can-i-resize-the-video-bytes-to-smaller-resolution-in-java

More Info : https://techgnious.github.io/IVCompressor